# Calling a webservice in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to make a Firefox extension which will use a webservice. I was looking online to find a way to do this. I was wondering if someone could explain what the following objects/methods do:

`service.useService(___, ___);`
`service.<Service Name>.callService();`

If there is an alternative that does not include these objects, I would be happy to hear about it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Was the correct answer provided?  If so, you should accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using IE specific code to call the webservice, and according to this response it may not be supported in newer browsers now:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31984555/you-can-use-xmlhttpreques.aspx

For more on the `service.useservice` function you may find this page helpful:
http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040708.htm

If you have control over the web service then you can get it to either reply with a JSON or use a REST web service, as well as a SOAP web service, as javascript can work well with REST, or with a form-based (POST/GET) web service, as opposed to SOAP.